# Opa : adding data to <head>

Tags: html, head, opa

How can I add specific markusp like meta, script, ... into the head section of an html document using Oap ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a full control of your page, you can use `Resource.full_page`
http://doc.opalang.org/value/stdlib.core.web.resource/Resource/full_page

Read the Resource module doc for other functions: http://doc.opalang.org/module/stdlib.core.web.resource/Resource